# When scaling a Cloud Foundry app, is the memory split among the instances?

Tags: cloud-foundry, microservices, scaling

I have an application deployed through Cloud Foundry which has to be scaled. This can be achieved using the command [`cf scale`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-scale.html), where the scaling can be done either *horizontally* (adjust number of instances) or *vertically* (adjust disk space limit and memory limit).

Suppose that I scale my  application such that it has 5 instances and 32 GB memory. Does **each** instance get to have 32 GB memory, or is the memory divided among the 5 instances, resulting in 6.4 GB memory per instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory and disk specified are on a per application instance basis [1].

In your example:

- App Instance 1: 32Gb memory
- App Instance 2: 32Gb memory
- App Instance 3: 32Gb memory
- App Instance 4: 32Gb memory
- App Instance 5: 32Gb memory

[1] https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-scale.html